# How can I access my service's through exposed NodePort when I enable mtls with Istio?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I previously had a bunch of microservices running fine without mtls enabled, that I could access via my frontend `http://192.168.99.100:31001/`, backend(s), and db running on various other NodePort's.

For the next stage of my project I need to enable mtls to accomplish securing my services via a JWT token controlled by istio. But, when I use istio-auth-demo instead of istio-demo I cannot access my services via their endpoint. What do I need to do to fix this? I have wrote a gateway, virtualservice, and destinationrules that I thought might clear up the issue.

Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: try to execute some helath check command to provide more information: `kubectl get service` `kubectl get endpoints` `kubectl get pod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what was the issue here. Maybe it was because I was running it on minikube and some config wasn't supported. I just enabled mtls on the pods I wanted and ran the regular version of istio.